# std::set different comparer for inserting and ordering

Tags: c++, set, containers, priority-queue

I need a structure in which I can insert elements, have no duplicate, use a custom comparer and have the smallest element first. I tried using `std::priority_queue`, but the problem is that I get a lot of duplicates and I run out of space. So I thought about using `std::set` : 
`std::set< std::pair<Coordinates, int>, Compare> positions;` where

```
Coordinates
{
public:
    Coordinates(int x = 0, int y = 0, char tool = 'T') : x(x), y(y), tool(tool) {}

public:
    int x, y;
    char tool;
};
```

```
class Compare
{
public:
    bool operator() (const std::pair<Coordinates, int>& c1, const std::pair<Coordinates, int>& c2) const
    {
        return c1.second < c2.second;
    }
};
```

I want the elements to be sorted based on the second element of pair, which this implementation is doing, but the problem is that it is using the same comparer when inserting new pairs and I get duplicates. 
 My question is: Is it possible to make the `std::set` to not allow duplicates also to order the elements based on the second element of pair?

Edit: Eliminated some code that was not necessary and changed in `Compare` > with <

Comment: `return c1.x == c2.x ? c1.y == c2.y ? true : false : false;` -- I feel sorry for the person trying to decipher this.  Why not simply `return (c1.x == c2.x && c1.y == c2.y);`?

Comment: Can you show how you are getting duplicates?  `std::set` wont store duplicates.

Comment: If I have in the ```std::set``` the following elements (Coordinates(1,1,T),2) and I want to insert in the set (Coordinates(2,0,T),2) it won't insert it. It compares it with (Coordinates(1,1,T),2) by the second parameter and returns false and it won't insert it. You're right Paul I overcomplicated that return ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your `Comparer` the `set` will contain only unique values of the `int`, since `Coordinates` isn't participating in the comparison at all.

`std::set` uses `operator <` for sorting as well as equality; equality is determined as `!(a<b || b<a)`. Therefore `operator <` should take into account every attribute which makes the element unique.

You can specialize `std::less` for your type like this:

```
namespace std {
template<>
struct less<pair<Coordinates, int>> {
    bool operator()(const pair<Coordinates, int>& a, const pair<Coordinates, int>& b) const {
        return tie(a.second, a.first.x, a.first.y) < tie(b.second, b.first.x, b.first.y);
    }
};
}
```

Then `std::set< std::pair<Coordinates, int>> positions;` should work.

Comment: You and @NathanOliver- Reinstate Monica posted almost at the same time (you faster with 1minute) so I'm gonna respond here for both answers. This is really ingenious I didn't know you could do something like this. This really solves my problem and does exactly what I wanted thanks for both of you for your answers were really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that since you only look at `second` in you comparator, you can only store pairs that have unique values for `second`.  This is because the set only uses the comparator to compare the elements.  It doesn't use your `operator ==` to check for equality but instead does `cmp(a, b) == cmp(b, a)`<sup>1</sup> to test if the values are equal.

If you wan to sort by `second`, but allow other points with the same `second` but different other values then you need to add those values into you comparator.  The easiest way to do that is to use `std::tie` to build a couple of tuples and use the tuples `operator <` which "does the right thing".  That would look like

```
class Compare
{
public:
    bool operator() (const std::pair<Coordinates, int>& c1, const std::pair<Coordinates, int>& c2) const
    {
        return std::tie(c1.second, c1.first.x, c1.first.y)  < std::tie(c2.second, c2.first.x, c2.first.y);
    }
};
```

<sup>1</sup>: If `a` is not less then `b`, and `b` is not less than `a` then `a` and `b` must be equal

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the issue was that you only looked at the second member of the pair, so the set didn't care if the Coordinates were different. You simply needed to include the Coordinates in your comparison.

Unlike the other answers, this one utilizes a lambda for the comparison. I prefer it over `std::tie` and mucking around with `std` overrides. It also saves you the trouble of writing up a functor yourself like you did with your Compare class.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class Coordinates {
public:
  Coordinates(int x = 0, int y = 0, char tool = 'T') : x(x), y(y), tool(tool) {}

  int x, y;
  char tool;
};

int main() {
  using CoordPair = std::pair<Coordinates, int>;

  auto compare = [](const CoordPair& a, const CoordPair& b) {
    if (a.second != b.second)
      return a.second < b.second;

    // Replace this with some method of comparing Coordinates
    return a.first.x != b.first.x || a.first.y != b.first.y;
  };

  std::set<std::pair<Coordinates, int>, decltype(compare)> list(compare);

  list.emplace(Coordinates(1, 1), 2);
  list.emplace(Coordinates(2, 0), 2);
  list.emplace(Coordinates(1, 1), 3);
  list.emplace(Coordinates(1, 1), 2); // Shouldn't show up

  for (auto i : list)
    std::cout << '(' << i.first.x << ", " << i.first.y << ", " << i.first.tool
              << ')' << ", " << i.second << '\n';
}
```

Your C++ version wasn't specified, this needs at least C++11.

Comment: Other answers were both exactly what I was looking for, but to be honest I like more your approach and the use of the lambda function for comparison. Really interesting thanks for posting this answer and for the example.